Errro "unexpected character and invalid character
the following code is yielding several errors
"unexpected character after attribute value."
"invalid character in attribute name."
"unexpected character after/ in tag. Expected >."
"expected closing tag. unexpected end of file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
h2 {text-align: center;}
p {text-align: center;}
</style>
<h2>King of Tyre Lodge #3</h2>
<p>Click to Visit Payment Portal.</p>
<a href="https://kotlodge3.square.site"</a> <img src="https://kingdavidgrandlodge.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/kot3-pay-site-540-x-540-px_270.png"> <class="center"> <width=50%;height=50%;>


<class="center"> and <width=50%;height=50%;> are not valid HTML elements. And your 'a' element is not formed correctly.
